# access google drive with gdrive from terminal

Tags: file-upload, google-drive-api

I am using gdrive to upload files to google drive from terminal. I used the token the first time I ran gdrive to establish the connection and usccessfully uploaded a file. When I tried the second time with:

`$ gdrive upload /home/gigiux/backup/2016-12-25.tar.gz`

I got:

```
 $ Uploading /home/gigiux/backup/2016-12-25.tar.gz
Failed to upload file: Post https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?alt=json&fields=id%2Cname%2Csize%2Cmd5Checksum%2CwebContentLink&uploadType=multipart: Post https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token: dial tcp: lookup accounts.google.com on 127.0.1.1:53: read udp 127.0.0.1:37601->127.0.1.1:53: i/o timeout
```

Does this mean that every time I run gdrive I need to re'set the connection with google drive and get a new token? Or is it a problem with the connection? but when I run:

```
$ gdrive list
```

I get the list of the files on google drive so there is indeed a connection and an access.
thank you

Comment: The error message says "io timeout"

Comment: If this is a connection issue, then you can verify it by trying to repeat the process of uploading a file. Try to check this [tutorial](http://olivermarshall.net/how-to-upload-a-file-to-google-drive-from-the-command-line/) if it can help you.

Comment: Is `gdrive upload` a python script that you have written? Even from a terminal console, Google Drive API doesn't work without *OAuth credentials*, meaning you have to create an app and grant permission (one-time process) to the app to access drive files on your behalf. Did you do that?

Comment: I am writing it as a shell script; I got the permission once from terminal and that is why I got the **gdrive list** working. If I have to get the permission each time I run the script, then _gdrive_ is no longer an efficient way to store data in batch, unless there is a way to connect with a simple shell command that could be used in a script.

Comment: If the problem is in the connection, is there a shell command that I could use to test the connection and launch the **gdrive** command if the connection is OK and try again later otherwise?